# How to find Duplicate element in a Table- Sybase

Tags: sql, sybase

I have a table Tzipcode which has fields 'zipcode','cityName','country' etc. Some zipcodes are repeating, in the sense same Zipcode for more than one city.

I want to find out those zipcodes that exist more than once in the table.
Also those zipcodes that exist more than twice.

Database: Sybase ASE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

Select zipcode, count(cityName) from Tzipcode group by zipcode having count(cityName) > 1

Comment: It didn't worked. Incorrect Syntax near the having keyword.